# Webpage endless scrolling down

Tags: html, infinite-scroll

So I've received this project to improve a webpage and it has a weird behaviour. When the resolution is smaller than 900px (small laptops and tablets) and you get to the end of the page you can scroll down endlessly after the footer image (it appears the background image repeating itself). This also happens with all resolutions when I have firebug opened. All divs are properly closed. I really don't know what is behind this behaviour. Maybe someone saw it before...

Here's my footer:

```
<footer>

 <div id="footer">

  <div id="footerContainer">

   <div id="footerMain">

    <div id="legal"></div>

    <div id="footerNav">

      <img src="images/table-footer.png" alt="">

     </div>

    </div>

   </div>

 </div>

</footer>

<a href="#" id="toTop"></a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the html you have posted... could you link to the website in question?

Comment: Wow! Why do you need so many divs wrapped around a single image?! I agree with @Tim you should post the link to the site so we can see what's going on. Or maybe make a jsfiddle for it.

Comment: works ok for me, btw nice design, and be sure your contact for input fields are little offset from the background

Comment: It is not my project. I just received it like that and I'm supposed to make it look better.

Comment: @Mr. Alien Have you tried with firebug opened or with resolution under 900px? small laptops..

Comment: Oh ya I see, this is something you need to fix I don't think someone will go through your whole website to find that bug, I guess something must be wrong with your jQuery

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga to me it looks like your problem is that your little guy that's moving down with the navigation on his shirt is moved down past the bottom of the screen. Making the browser think there is more area below. Then when you scroll down he moves farther, giving more space to scroll. Then you end up with an infinitely long page. Maybe instead of changing the top value on him try having a bottom value instead?

Comment: @CaldwellYSR Ya it could be the issue, haha that little guy must be causing big scrolling problems

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks. At least now I identified the problem. See how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #toTop anchor is being pushed down below the bottom of the viewport when the screen height is below a certain number. This is because whatever script is being used changes the top value of that anchor to be x amount more than the scrolled position. A better way to accomplish this same effect would be to make the bottom value of the guy be something like 10 more than the bottom of the viewport. Then he won't go down too far and cause the browser to think there's more space than there is.